# Driving mode media tray missing

Tags: media-player, google-maps-navigation, driving-mode

I have a Pixel 8 Pro with Android 14; for years I have used my Android phones for car navigation. Like many, I like to use my phone to listen to Pandora, Spotify, podcast players etc. While in Driving Mode, there is... or *was* a tray at the bottom of the screen I could click to view all of the available media providers (everything presented with giant buttons to reduce driving distraction), select the one I wanted to use, and select from the selected provider which music channel, podcast, etc. I wanted to listen to.

Recently this tray has simply disappeared and for the life of me I can't figure out what happened or how to get it back again. I've searched through system settings and driving mode settings and if there is anything related to this behavior I haven't been able to find it. I also tried clearing the cache of some apps and many system services, but this has not fixed the issue.

Wondering if anyone has an idea what is going on and how to restore this UI element to driving mode.

Comment: Just making sure you didn't install Google Gemini as `If you opt in to the Gemini app, it will replace your Google Assistant as the primary assistant on the phone. You can switch back to Google Assistant in settings.` from the Google Play Store entry for [Google Gemini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.bard&hl=en_US&gl=US)

Comment: Are you using Android Auto or some other app?

Comment: @RohitGupta Android Auto was deprecated by Google and replaced by Driving Mode. I am not using any replacement for Driving Mode.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I uninstalled Gemini then checked Google Assistant settings; this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Google app. According to a thread on the Android Auto community, you can get the media tray back by downgrading the Google app to version 14.39, and the problem will be fixed.Now, to downgrade an app, according to How To Geek, You can downgrade most Android apps by going to Settings > Apps > Manage Apps and choosing to “Uninstall Updates” for a particular app, but this will also log out and remove all your app data.  To downgrade an app and keep your data, set up Android Debug Bridge and sideload an app using the APK file for the version you want.  Finally, avoid unwanted updates in the Play Store by going to Settings > Network Preferences > Auto-Update Apps and selecing “Don’t Auto-Update Apps.”

Comment: The issue is not that Driving Mode is not active, the issue is that while Driving Mode is active, the media tray is missing.